# How do I write grave accent inside code?

Tags: support

Sometimes I need to write a grave accent formatted as code inline, but I can't do this, because the renderer recognizes it as syntax to write code.

*Example:*

---

Grave accent + Grave accent + Grave accent
```

---

Grave accent + space + Grave accent + space + Grave accent

`

---

Grave accent + space + Grave accent + Grave accent + space + Grave accent
``` `` ```

---

As you see, the last one works, and I need something like that with just one Grave accent.

Comment: What if you escape the grave? `$str = '\` hello'` with a `\` \.

Comment: How? i just need a grave accent formatted as code

Comment: `\`` <-- here is a tick mark, preceded by a backslash, surrounded by two tick marks.

Comment: Code inline is usually a bad habit as screen readers will usually read backtick the code backtick

Comment: @Tensibai Stupid comment parsing :(.

Comment: dont hate me, but which are tick marks?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan my bad, it work with a slightly different manner in answers too ;)

Comment: @LeviArista Same key as a "grave accent".

Comment: @LeviArista underneath the `esc` key.

Comment: Is this on-topic on meta site?

Comment: @AlexL Certainly, since this is about how to add backticks in code _on Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain this: `` ` `` I just wrote:

```
To obtain this: `` ` ``
```